# Multiple download of files at once in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have added a function where in when the user select multiple order then trigger the `Download PDF` button I added it will download PDF's with X number of PDF based from the number of selected orders. So basically when I select 3 PDF it should generate or download 3 PDF. But on my function it only download one pdf. How can I tell Magento 2 to download 3 pdf or more based from the number of selected items.

Below is my sample code

```
public function printPDF()
{
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
    $style->setFont($font,13);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $width = $page->getWidth();
    $hight = $page->getHeight();
    $x = 30;
    $pageTopalign = 850; 
    $this->y = 850 - 100; 

    $style->setFont($font,14);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y +70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

    $style->setFont($font,13);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Cutomer Details"), $x + 5, $this->y+50, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Name : %1", "Test Meetanshi"), $x + 5, $this->y+33, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Email : %1","test@meetanshi.com"), $x + 5, $this->y+16, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);

    $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT NAME"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("PRODUCT PRICE"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("QTY"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("SUB TOTAL"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $add = 9;

    $page->drawText("$12.00", $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(10, $x + 330, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText("$120.00", $x + 470, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $pro = "TEST product";
    $page->drawText($pro, $x + 65, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');

    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 10, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y - 100, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);

    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Total : %1", "$50.00"), $x + 435, $this->y-85, 'UTF-8');

    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Test Footer example"), ($page->getWidth()/2)-50, $this->y-200);

    $fileName = 'meetanshi.pdf';

    $this->fileFactory->create(
       $fileName,
       $pdf->render(),
       \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR, // this pdf will be saved in var directory with the name meetanshi.pdf
       'application/pdf'
    );
}
```

So in my `execute()` function I added this call

```
public function execute()
{
        $this->printPDF();
        $this->printPDF();
        $this->printPDF();
}
```

But it only download 1 PDF. How can I tell it to download multiple times?

Update:

- I was also thinking of merging multiple files into single PDF file by adding multiple page in this PDF. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it the following way, by using Zend_Pdf::parse and merging the pages at the end

```
           $finalPdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
            foreach ($pdfs as $pdf) {
                    $parsed = \Zend_Pdf::parse($pdf);

                foreach ($parsed->pages as $page) {
                    $clonedPage = clone $page;
                    $finalPdf->pages[] = $clonedPage;
                }
            }
            return $finalPdf;
```